# Community has 5 rep?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just noticed that the [Community](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user has 5 rep instead of their normal 1 rep. Is this some weird bug or normal/expected behavior? If it is normal then what is the reason to give Community more rep on Meta. Note that Community only has one rep on our [main site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) and on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

[image: community has five rep]

Comment: Moderators can't access Meta sites unless they have 5 reputation... perhaps that's it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Interesting... That probably explains it, but it begs the question of why moderators can't access meta sites with less than 5 rep and how a (non-community) moderator could have less than five rep. Presumably a moderator would have enough rep somewhere to get the association bonus

Comment: Those are the assumptions SE made in designing the system (that moderators would 99.9999% of the time have enough rep), which is why that's the only privilege that moderator status doesn't override.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I never thought of the community user as a user that needed to adhere to the rep rules. If you can find a reference that supports your comment I'll gladly up-vote and accept your answer. As an aside even though 4 rep is exceedingly small, I don't understand why that limit is in place at all. That's a separate question though which probably has to do with a spamming problem knowing how the interwebs work....

Comment: The 5-rep limit is indeed because of spam... it halves the number of sites we have to work to protect. I can't actually find a reference for my comment - I believe I found out about it from a conversation (with a dev?) in the Teachers' Lounge, which is unquotable.

Comment: @ArtOfCode A side effect is that it prevents suspended users posting on the meta site. For some reason I always imagined that was the reason for the limit.

Comment: Related (unanswered) on meta.SE: [Is Community ♦ supposed to have 1 rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234706/194636)

Comment: Also:  [Help Center > Privileges > Participate In Meta](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta). Perhaps Community is given 5 rep on per-site metas to avoid possible bugs. Dunno. Seems like the sort of thing nervous/paranoid SE devs might do.

Comment: @PaulWhite I would have agreed until I read your linked above. It appears as if 5 rep isn't universal. Some [Community](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) users have 3 rep, and I assume they can still function as normal...

Comment: Hence me not adding an answer. Perhaps Community managed to lose 2 rep? I don't know. I am curious to find out though :)

Comment: + NINE THOUSAND

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We try to never let the bots earn rep, but this one became sentient.  I challenged Community to a battle of epic proportions and removed the extra 4 reputation by force.  Lesson learned:  never trust robots

Comment: I was rooting for you the whole time. +1 for humanity.